# How can I find one element of the object in an arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of Employee class objects.

Every employee has *id*, *fname*, *lname*, etc. I need to get index of element where employee ID's is for example 1234521953. How can I find out the index in which the employee is located? Every ID is unique, and that's why I am trying to find him/her by ID.

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    private String employerName;
    private LocalDate employmentDate;
    private LocalDate releaseDate;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private String jobtitle;
}
```

There is my class Person:

```
public class Person {
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private long id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String addressLine;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
}
```

I am adding them in for to:

```
List<Employee> employeesAL = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: SHare the code of Employee class and the list pleae

Comment: edited! Added Employee class and the arraylist where i add them

Comment: Ok, I've edit my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have implemented the `.equals` method in `Employee` class you may just pass it to `.indexOf()`

```
List<Employee> l = new ArrayList<>();
Employee e = new Employee("ID123");
int idx = l.indexOf(e);
```

As the `ID` is unique, you don't need to check all the fields in the `.equals()` method, just check the `ID` :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee) o;
    return id == employee.id;
}
```

---

Or implement it yourself, using the same logic of `indexOf`

```
int idx = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    if (e.getId() == l.get(i).getId()) {
        idx = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @tadziuuuuu I can't know, but as advice : post a minimal working example for your code, here for example all the getters and setters are useless, only the class structure (attributes) are needed ;)

Comment: Okk, from now my posts will look better :D

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```java
public Employee getEmployee(String id) {
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        if (employee.getId().equals(id)) {
            return employee;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But it will be slow if there are a lot of employees in the list because it iterates over the list. If you want to look up employees quickly by ID, I would recommend you use a Map (e.g. `HashMap`) keyed on the id with Employee as the value.

Another alternative would be to ensure that the `Employee` objects in the list are kept in order of id. Then you could do a binary search of the list to find an Employee with a specific id.

Answer (score 0):

A modern way is using the streams API:

```
public Optional<Employee> getEmployee(String id) {
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeesAL.stream()
          .filter(employee -> id.equals(employee.getId()))
          .findAny();

    return employee;
}
```

This method returns `Optional<Employee>` because you can't guarantee that an employee can be found for every ID you pass in. [This page](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) has a good guide for working with Optionals.

Answer (score 0):

The answers of users @azro and @elevate is correct. But if you're using Java 8 and up you can use the following to find an element:

```
List<Employee> employeesAL = new ArrayList<>();
....
public Employee findEmployee(long id) {
    Optional<Employee> optionalEmployee = employeesAl.stream()
                                         .filter(e -> e.getId() == id)
                                         .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

**Note:** Note that returning null from a method is bad old habit. If you know how to use the Optional class, it is the better way of returning a value from a method which can be null; so you can inform the client the value can be null and it should handle this case.

Comment: The list should be a parameter, and instead of using `isPresent()` use `orElse` which does the same of your code  `return employeesAL.stream().filter(e -> e.getId() == id).findFirst().orElse(null);
`

Comment: @azro Thanks you're right; and I'll edit the answer.